# SageMath: matrix_plot not returning any output within a subroutine

Tags: sage

```
A=identity_matrix(2)
def f(n):
    matrix_plot(n*A)
f(5)
```

I'm puzzled as the command `matrix_plot(5*A)` works fine on itself, but it produces no output when it goes inside a subroutine as in the above SageMath code.

I'd appreciate any help with understanding why this is so/resolving this.

PS I have tested this both on Sagecell.sagemath.org and a local installation.

Comment: Also asked as [Ask Sage question 56666](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/56666).

Answer (score 1):

As written, the function computes the matrix plot
but does not return it and does not display it.

To have the function display it:

```
def f(n, A):
    matrix_plot(n*A).show()
```

To have the function return the plot (probably better):

```
def f(n, A):
    return matrix_plot(n*A)
```

Then

```
sage: n = 5
sage: A = identity_matrix(2)
sage: f(n, A)
```